# Closing a tab open in Chrome Extension before main window closes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome Extension that opens an external (detached) window that is meant to be open for the rest of the session.

I'd like to get an event when the main window (with many tabs) is closing so that I close my tab before the main window. Otherwise, the tab will remain open and the user needs to close it manually. Thus, Chrome will remember it as the next time Chrome will open it instead of the other tabs that were in the main window. Obviously, this is a bad user experience.

The background script doesn't get any event when the main window closes.

Any idea how I could get this?

Comment: Sorry for initially considering your question trivial. What you want is preserving the "main" window as the last window closed for session restoration purposes. `windows.onRemoved` will be too late.

Comment: Have you considered opening your window as an incognito window?

Comment: That works. Thanks. I'm afraid that I'd need to store some session information and that could not work with the incognito session. Is there a formal way to do this without this workaround?

Comment: I can think of a very, very UGLY one I shall not even mention.. Does that window contain a page from your extension or an external website? Note that with `spanning` Incognito behavior you can fake persistence.

Comment: It's loading a server page. If there's not easy way, I'll go with this workaround for now. Although I don't find it perfect that the extension tab is left orphan. Thanks.

Comment: doesn't the chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener works here?

Comment: It works but it involved doing a lot of housekeeping to restore the other tabs. I implemented that when I discovered that opening the window with type equal to panel makes it like incognito in the sense that it doesn't overwrite other windows closed before while having the advantage of allowing me to use the local and session storage